# How to add a tag to the front page/favorites when browsing

Tags: support, tags, user-interface

When I am browsing a tag on Stack Overflow (e.g. [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading)), is there an easy way to add it to my front page/"favorite tags"? If I hover over the button, a "subscribe" link appears on the right, but it turns out to mean notification by e-mail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on that star next to the "subscribe" link.

http://phpcode.eu/images/1315004194.png

Comment: Thanks, this has frustrated me for a year! Is this obvious? I imagine there are thousands of users frustrated like I was.

Comment: @MattHickford: don't be. I didn't know about this feature before!

Comment: This is a UI discoverability failure. It should be fixed ASAP. Alas, the establishment don't care, because they are familiar with the interface.

Answer (score 4):

Hover the tag in a question listed in the page you reported as example; in the drop down that appears, click on the star you see at the left side.

[image: screenshot]

(The screenshot shows the drop-down for [android](/questions/tagged/android).)

This is valid for any tag shown, including the one that is common to all the questions listed in that page (in this case, [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading)). To say it all, it is valid in any page that lists questions, and their tags.